# How to load several pickle files at the same time to optimiz loading time for large pickle files?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pickle

I have 12 pickle files, each containing a list of dictionaries. I need to load all of them before processing. However, each file is approximately 4 GB, and loading them one after another takes a long time. I have tried parallelization options, but they didn't work. I am considering having parent and child scripts, where each child script reads one file, and then I concatenate them. The pickle files are three-dimensional (longitude, latitude, and month), and I want to concatenate them based on the month dimension as follows:

```
import pickle
import os
import xarray as xr
import yaml

# Access the filepath from the configuration
file_path = "/pickle/file/dir/"

loaded_data = []

# Get a list of pickle filenames in the directory and sort them
pickle_files = [filename for filename in os.listdir(file_path) if filename.endswith(".pkl")]
pickle_files = sorted(pickle_files)

# Loop through all files in the directory
for filename in pickle_files:
    if filename.endswith(".pkl"):  # Check if the file has a .pkl extension
        file_path = os.path.join(file_path, filename)
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            data = pickle.load(file)
            loaded_data.append(data)

final_data = xr.concat(loaded_data, dim='month')
```